# On the convergence of sequences by recurrence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Hello I'm studying some problems on computer science in which arises the following recurrence sequences:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k + x_{n}}$$
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1/n + x_{n}}$$

$x_{0} = \epsilon >0$  for both and $k>0$.

What do you think about convergence on both?

Comment: I think I want to know what you think first.

Comment: You could try to think about how $x_n$ and $n$ compare as n grows. And then ask yourself if the sequence is monotone at some point.

Comment: I'm a little lost, can you explain it better?

Comment: For the 1st one you can try Banach fixed point theorem, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729836/showing-the-sequence-converges-a-1-frac12-a-n1-frac12a-n/2729943#2729943) is an example

Answer (score 0):

The first one converges
for $k > .6$.

From
$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k + x_{n}}$,
$x_n < \frac1{k}$.

Therefore
$x_n > \frac1{k+1/k}$.

Therefore
$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1} 
= \frac{1}{k + x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{k + x_{n}}
= \frac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{(k + x_{n+1})(k + x_{n})}
$
so
$|\dfrac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_n-x_{n+1}} |
= |\frac{1}{(k + x_{n+1})(k + x_{n})}|
\lt |\frac{1}{(k + 1/(k+1/k))^2}|
= |\frac{1}{(k + k/(k^2+1))^2}|
= |\frac{(k^2+1)^2}{(k(k^2+1) + k)^2}|
= |\frac{(k^2+1)^2}{(k^3+2k)^2}|
\lt 1
$
for $x > .6$
according to Wolfy.