# Find limit of $(a_n)$ defined by $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3+a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence defined by $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3+a_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$ Show that $(a_n)$ converges and find its limit.

I have no idea on how to handle this though so I would definitely appreciate some help for a rigorous proof.

Comment: For part b are you able to show that the sequence is bounded above by $\frac 13$ and below by $0$?

Comment: Part $b)$ of your post is a question found in Mathematics Magazine about 2 years ago. Look that up. To do that sequence, you have to consider subsequence...

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun Its an exercise consisted of 2 parts and I only asked one question. Please review the posts better before commenting (and potentially downvoting).

Comment: @DeepSea A subsequence approach seems rather interesting ! I'll check it up, thanks !

Comment: Because I am slow at typing, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729836/showing-the-sequence-converges-a-1-frac12-a-n1-frac12a-n/) as an example.

Comment: If you use [Approach 0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%2Ba_n%7D%24&p=1), one can find this questions easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we note that $a_n\in (0,1/3)$ for $n>1$.

Since
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{3+a_n}-\frac{1}{3+a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n-1}-a_n}{(3+a_n)(3+a_{n-1})},$$
and $(3+a_n)(3+a_{n-1})>9$, we see that 
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac19 |a_n-a_{n-1}|.$$
This shows that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, so it converges to some number $a\in[0,1/3]$. To find $a$, take limits on both sides of 
$$a_{n+1}=\frac1{3+a_n}.$$

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I missed that. It is true when $n>1$.

Comment: Yes I saw that, I deleted my comment. You could also use Banach's theorem about contractions here, maybe you should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [contraction mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225451/contraction-mapping-in-the-context-of-fx-n-x-n1/2225503#2225503) technique. We will look at the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{3+x}$ s.t. $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$.

1. $\forall x \in \left[0,1\right] => f(x) \in \left[0,1\right]$. Indeed 
   $$0\leq x\leq 1 \Rightarrow 3\leq 3+x\leq 4 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}\geq \frac{1}{3+x}\geq \frac{1}{4}>0$$ or $$1\geq f(x)\geq 0$$
2. $f(x)$ is a contraction mapping on $\left[0,1\right]$, from [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) $\forall x,y \in \left[0,1\right], \exists c$ in between them s.t.
   $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y|=\left|-\frac{1}{(3+c)^2}\right||x-y|\leq\frac{1}{9}|x-y|$$

Since $a_1 \in \left[0,1\right]$, from Banach fixed-point theorem, the sequence has a limit on $\left[0,1\right]$ which you can find from $L=\frac{1}{3+L}$.