# Proving Cauchy of the sequence: $ \ x_{n+1} = \frac 1{2+x_n} $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1 = \frac 12$ .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Below is my attempt at doing this, would love to get some feedback on it and find out if there is anything I can improve!

---

For two terms in succession (for each integer $n\geq 2$):

> $ \displaystyle | x_{n+1} - x_{n}| = \frac { | x_{n} - x_{n-1} | }{ (2+x_n) (2+x_{n-1} ) } < \frac 14 | x_n - x_{n-1} | < \frac 1{4^2} | x_{n-1} - x_{n-2} | < \ldots < \frac 1{4^{n-1}} | x_{n-(n-2)} - x_{n-(n-1)}  | = \frac 1{4^ {n-1} } | x_2 - x_1| = \frac {c_1}{4^{n-1} }. $
>
> Here $c_1 = |x_2 - x_1| = | \frac 25 - \frac 12| > 0$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find an integer $N \geq 1$ such that for each integer $n,m \geq N$ we have $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$.

Without loss of generality suppose $m > n \geq N$, where $N$ will soon be chosen judiciously.

The distance from $x_m$ to $x_n$ is less than the sum of the distances of successive terms starting at $n$ up to $m$. Namely:

> $ |x_m - x_n| \leq |x_m - x_{m-1}| + |x_{m-1} - x_{m-2}| + \ldots + | x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} | + | x_{n+1} - x_n |  .  $
>
> We can control each term since we know distances of successive terms:
>
> $ \displaystyle |x_m - x_n | \leq \frac {c_1}{ 4^{m-2} } + \frac {c_1}{ 4^{m-3} } + \ldots + \frac {c_1}{ 4^n } + \frac {c_1}{ 4^{n-1} } = \frac {c_1}{ 4^{n-1} } \cdot \left( \frac 1{4^{m-n-1}} + \frac 1{4^{m-n-2}} + \ldots + \frac 1{4} + 1   \right)       $

The latter factor is a finite geometric sum with $0 < x < 1$ (in our case $x = 1/4$) and can be bounded above by a constant:

> $ \displaystyle |1 + x+ x^2 + \ldots + x^n| = \frac {|1 - x^{n+1}|}{1-x} \leq \frac 2{1-x} \equiv c_2 $

Thus:

> $ \displaystyle |x_m - x_n | \leq  \frac {c_1}{ 4^{n-1} } \cdot \left( \frac 1{4^{m-n-1}} + \frac 1{4^{m-n-2}} + \ldots + \frac 1{4} + 1   \right)  <  \frac {c_1 \cdot c_2}{4^{n-1}}  < \frac {c_1 \cdot c_2}{4^{N-1}}  $

This upper bound depends on $N$ and by choosing it large enough we can make it smaller than the given $\epsilon$ (by Archimedean property).

Hence an integer $N$ exists for which $|x_m - x_n| < \epsilon$, which establishes the fact that the sequene is Cauchy. Done. $\blacksquare$

---

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perfect solution I think.

Comment: You will find a few more solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729836/showing-the-sequence-converges-a-1-frac12-a-n1-frac12a-n/).

Comment: Thank you both!